# Asterisk - Dial between two local phones

Tags: asterisk, pbx

On the softphone, I have connected two accounts tom and paul as a testing purpose. On the tom device, I have dialled extention 100 and it did ring on the paul device. When I answer the call I can hear the background music and it did NOT execute `same  =>   n,Playback(demo-moreinfo)`

What is causing this?

I have two sip trunks in sip.conf file:

```
[office-phone](!)
type=friend
context=LocalSets
host=dynamic
nat=yes
secret=password
dtmfmode=auto
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw

[tom](office-phone)
[paul](office-phone)
```

In the extension.conf file:

```
[LocalSets]
exten =>   100,1,Dial(SIP/paul)
same  =>   n,Playback(demo-moreinfo)
same  =>   n,Hangup()
```

Comment: please provide asterisk CLI output in verbose mode. (i.e. `asterisk -rvvvvv`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[LocalSets]
; Dial connets the callee and caller channels.
exten =>   100,1,Dial(SIP/paul)
; Otherwise Playback is executed (after a Dial timeout occurs)
same  =>   n,Playback(demo-moreinfo)
same  =>   n,Hangup()
```

Like in this example, when the call goes unanswered, play the vm-nobodyavail sound.

```
exten => 123,1,Dial(SIP/100,10,m)
;; if the the call is answered, the next priority is never executed
exten => 123,n,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)
exten => 123,n,Hangup()
```

If you would like to play a soundfile, the Answer application makes sures the channel connected, and the next priority could execute `Playback`.

```
exten => 100,1,Answer()
exten => 100,n,Playback(demo-moreinfo)
```

In this example, when somebody dials 100, the call will be answered by the Answer application. Then the caller will hear the sound file.

```
exten => 100,1,Answer()
 same => n,Noop("100 answered")
 same => n,Playback(demo-moreinfo)
 ; same => n,Noop("heard the info, dial 200")
 ; same => Dial(SIP/200);
 same => n,Hangup()
```

You could execute `Dial` after `Playback`.

Comment: When the caller answered the call, I would like the caller to hear the `demo-moreinfo` sound

Comment: yes, Answer makes sure two Channels are connected, and the playback occurs. Have you tried the example?